# Retrieve and display data from mysql on ReactJS frontend

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am using NodeJS, MySQL Server, and ReactJS.

I have a local mysql server running that I am retrieving data in a file named `database.js`

**database.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'budget',
});

db.query('select * from transactions', (error, results, fields) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(results);
  }
});
```

I would like to display the `results` in my ReactJS component via the `transactions.jsx` file.

**transactions.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import {DataGrid, GridColDef, GridRowsProp} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import {Box} from "@mui/material";

const Transactions = () => {
  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {field: 'col1', headerName: 'Column 1', width: 150},
    {field: 'col2', headerName: 'Column 2', width: 150},
  ];

  const rows: GridRowsProp = [
    {id: 1, col1: 'Hello', col2: 'World'},
    {id: 2, col1: 'DataGridPro', col2: 'is Awesome'},
    {id: 3, col1: 'MUI', col2: 'is Amazing'},
  ];

  return (
    <Box sx={{
      height: `calc(100vh - 128px)`,
    }}>
      <DataGrid columns={columns} rows={rows}/>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Transactions;
```

Ultimately I would put the data inside `<DataGrid>` component.

Comment: What have you tried? At the moment your question shows no attempt at building a solution yourself.

Comment: I just found out I need to have a backend server that will act as an API. Then React can get data from the API. When I get it working I will post what I did to fix it.